# What can Not Enough Items do?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, mods

- What are the capabilities of NEI?
- Can NEI create potions like TMI? I know it can enchant, but I don't know about potions.
- Can it also create custom fireworks like TMI? 
  I would like to know the capabilities because I am creating a map and I custom potions and fireworks.

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using TMI, since you already know it does what you want?

Comment: I don't actually mess with any of the sorts of things you're asking about, but I was under the impression NEI was a *direct replacement* for TMI.

Comment: I use NEI for the fact that it shows recipes when not oped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. 1. give you items (a stack or a single at the time),
   2. set time of day to midnight, morning, noon or evening and disable them
   3. save and restore you items
   4. toggle and disable rain
   5. set you to and from creative mode (with an extra creative mode that allows use of the sidebar and a larger inventory)
   6. activate magnet mode
   7. heal the player
   8. check other recipes like smelting and brewing (mods with their own machines need a plugin for these recipes to show)
2. you can get all potions directly out of the side bar
3. no but you can check the recipes of the firework stars

Comment: By potions I mean like Nausea and Jump Boost.

Comment: you can also make potions by hitting "p"